# docx4J - Set default font or encoding to UTF-8 for docx output file

Tags: encoding, fonts, docx, docx4j

I'm using docx4j to make a translate apps with input file is docx and output is docx too. I have problems when working with chinese character input. That is the `w:rFonts` tag of input file: `<w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia" w:ascii="MingLiU" w:hAnsi="MingLiU" w:eastAsia="MingLiU" w:cs="MingLiU"/>`

How can i change to `Time New Roman` font in the output file or change the encoding to `UTF-8`. 
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding should be UTF-8 already.  That's standard for docx files.

The simplest way to change to "Times New Roman" is to set the attributes of the rFonts tag above.  That is, where it says "MingLiU"

To do that, get the rFonts object (in direct formatting, styles etc)

You should also change the font in rPrDefaults, since this takes effect anywhere where it isn't overridden by another rFonts tag.